# Raspberry Pi Pico not booting after power outage

Tags: pi-pico

My Pi Pico is working fine when connected to the laptop and running the program. It is also connected via Pin 39 (VSYS) and ground. When I unplug the usb the Pi keeps running without issue. However, when I shut off the power from the pins and reconnect the pins, it won't boot up again. If I reconnect the Laptop and run the program it is fine again.  Is there something I'm missing in the code to have it boot automatically after power outage? From what I understand the Pi should just resume operation once disconnected. Thanks for the input.

I'm running the following script:

```
from machine import Pin
import utime

utime.sleep(1.5)

valveStatus = Pin(16, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
led.on()

relay = Pin(15, Pin.OUT, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
relay.low()

print("Intitial Status:",valveStatus.value())

while True:
   print(valveStatus.value())
   print("valve is closed")
   utime.sleep(1)
   led.toggle()
    
   if valveStatus.value() == 1:
       print("Valve is open")
       relay.high()
       utime.sleep(10)
       relay.low()
```

Comment: the pico does not resume after power loss. You need an autostart script to resume activity after powering up the pico. Read the micropython documentation

Comment: The Pico does restart.  Perhaps this is a MicroPython problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had to reset it and reinstall the firmware. Now it works. Not sure what messed up the controller in the first place.